# Scrolling code in Android app causes display oddity

Tags: bug, android-app, code-block

When I use the Android app and use my finger to scroll the code over, the blue triangle in the upper-right corner moves with the code!

[image]

---

Versions:

- **Stack Exchange**: 1.0.30
- **Android**: 4.4

Comment: Scrollable code blocks will be the death of me... Thanks for reporting!

Comment: I find that I have to tap on the code block to open it in lightbox view, then I can scroll through them properly. In my opinion, I shouldn't need to open the code in such a lightbox view at all, and the original code block itself should be fully scrollable.

Comment: In the latest version, the lightbox view (which I think should be removed entirely) open twice, thrice or even five times like a layer cake when a code block is tapped on. Pressing the Back key removes the layers one by one.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.0.60, I longer see this problem; the Blue Triangle(tm) stays in its corner.

Thank you for fixing it!

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248524/241919) should be related :)